# Magento1.9.2 how to set my pincode in top links

Tags: estimate

I have created custom module for the set pincode same pincode is used for calculate shipping rate/estimate shipping rate.

Code in template/page/template/links.phtml :

```
<?php $shippingblock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_shipping'); ?>
    <div class="pincode" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Set your pincode"><span class=""></span> My Pincode:<span class="is-set"><?php echo $shippingblock->escapeHtml($shippingblock->getEstimatePostcode()) ?></span><a class="setzip" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#setlocation">set pincode</a><input type="hidden" id="charge-sales-tax" value=""></div>
```

My Custom controller  code

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setCountryId('US')->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setPostcode('27007')->save();
```

When I add product in the shopping cart then set my pin code it working fine.
But without adding product in cart then it won't work.

Please advice me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is ***`Magento fundamental logic`*** where without **`create a quote`** means **`without cart a product`** ,you cannot calculate shipping charge.

`Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()` quote object have value when **current session have any cart item**

For calculate shipping charges,you should cart a product else it is not possible.

Comment: Is there any way to calculate shipping rate on product listing and detail page?

Comment: not possible. ...As per as knowledge.Only possible if u implement custom module & custom business logic